# Remove Image From NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

So, the app that I'm writing allows the user to upload a photo from their camera roll, and it displays in a UIImageView. I have a "Save" button, that allows the images to be saved when pressed. I also have an "Edit" button, when tapped, it allows the user to tap on the photo and it will be deleted. This is where I'm having issues, the image deletes from the view, but doesn't seem to delete from the array. When I close and relaunch the app, the photo appears again. I'm very new to Objective-C, I'm surprised that I even made it this far, so I'm having issues figuring out how to delete it from the array.

Also, as a side note, if I grab 3 images from the camera roll, delete the middle one, and then press the save button, after closing and relaunching the app it displays only the 2 photos like it should. The issue regarding the image appearing again after relaunch only happens if I press save first, then try and delete them.

This is how I'm deleting them. I have an invisible button over each UIImageView, and when the Edit button is pressed, it unhides them. I've tagged both the buttons and the UIImageViews, and when one of the buttons is pressed, this fires:

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *deleteAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                              message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [deleteAlertView show];

    int imageIndex = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    deleteAlertView.tag = imageIndex;
}

- (UIImageView *)viewForTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    UIImageView *found = nil;
    for (UIImageView *view in self.array) {
        if (tag == view.tag) {
            found = view;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView 
clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex
{


    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

        UIImageView *view = [self viewForTag:alertView.tag];
        if (view) {
            [self.array removeObject:view];
        }

        ((UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:alertView.tag]).image =nil;
    }

    [self.user setObject:self.array forKey:@"images"];
}
```

And just for reference, this is how I'm saving the images:

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
        if (imageView.image == nil) {
            imageView.image = img;

            [self.array addObject:imageView];

            [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

            return;

        }

        if (imageView2.image == nil) {
            imageView2.image = img;
            NSLog(@"The image is a %@", imageView);
            [self.array addObject:imageView2];

            [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

            return;
        }
        ...
        ...
        }

    -(IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];



        for (UIImageView *imageViewToSave in self.array) {

            NSInteger tag = imageViewToSave.tag;
            UIImage *image = imageViewToSave.image;
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",tag];

            NSString *imagePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

            [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
        }

    }
```

And this is how I'm loading them:

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {

        self.array = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *docFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docsDir error:NULL];

        for (NSString *fileName in docFiles) {

            if ([fileName hasSuffix:@".png"]) {
                NSString *fullPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

                if (!imageView.image) {
                    imageView.image = loadedImage;
                } 
                else if (!imageView2.image) {
                    imageView2.image = loadedImage;
                  }
                else if (!imageView3.image) {
                    imageView3.image = loadedImage;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Here is my current code:

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Sender is %@", sender);
    UIAlertView *deleteAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                              message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [deleteAlertView show];

    int imageIndex = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    deleteAlertView.tag = imageIndex;
}

- (UIImageView *)viewForTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    UIImageView *found = nil;
    for (UIImageView *view in self.array) {
        if (tag == view.tag) {
            found = view;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView 
clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex
{


    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

        UIImageView *view = [self viewForTag:alertView.tag];
        if (view) {
            [self.array removeObject:view];

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",view.tag]];
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
        }

        ((UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:alertView.tag]).image =nil;
    }

    [self.user setObject:self.array forKey:@"images"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're deleting the image from the array `[self.array removeObject:view];`, you haven't removed the image itself from the directory.

You may want to do something like this after removing the object from `array`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"THE_IMAGE_NAME_HERE.png"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

if (error)
NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, should I add [fileManager removeItemAtPath:view error:NULL]; under [self.array removeObject:view];? Sorry for the novice question, still very new to this.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot. For `stringByAppendingPathComponent`, should I make that simply `view`? I use `view` to determine the tag of which UIImageView was tapped for deletion.

Comment: If `tag` is what you use to identify your images then you could do something like this: `[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",view.tag]];`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. However, the issue is still occurring. When I delete the image, it deletes from the view just fine. But when I close and relaunch the app, the image reappears. I updated the OP with my current code at the bottom.

Comment: Try inserting `NSLog(@"Tag: %d",view.tag);` and see what appears. It's possible that the objects in the array have no tag.

Comment: Cool thank you. That NSLog is outputting the correct tags for each picture, so I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: Well then you just use the code I gave you in a comment above to remove the file.

Comment: I added that code in, I updated the OP with my current code at the top. Your code did help out a lot, on test runs when I add in three images, hit the save button, then delete them, they delete perfectly. I can relaunch the app and the images are no longer there. But, if I add in three images, hit the save button then close and relaunch the app, then try to delete the photos, it does not work at all. The images disappear from the screen, but load again on relaunch. Very strange.

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling your delete function after you save? It seems odd to me that you are now having the complete opposite problem to what you had before. Before, they were not being deleted and kept appearing, but now they **are** being deleted but show up again. Could you maybe upload the class files somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: I actually was calling the delete function after the save, everything still works perfectly that way. The delete function only stops working after I completely close then relaunch the app, then try and delete the image. Its pretty weird. Sure here is my entire .h file: github.com/Joey502/Test-Thing/wiki/.h-Class-File And here is my entire .m file: github.com/Joey502/Test-Thing/wiki/.m-Class-File Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: When removing the file in your delete function, write `NSError *error;` and then, `[fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];`, and finally `NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);` and see what (if any) the error message is. I've edited the answer to include this.

Comment: Cool thank you sir, I just added that in and ran it. After deleting the pictures, there were no errors. The issue only seems to occur after I close the app, then close it from the multitasking bar as well, then relaunch it and try to delete them. That ends its run in Xcode when I close it in the multitasking bar, so unfortunately I can't read any of the console output after that point. But, there were no errors when simply deleting the photos without closing it.

Comment: Think I should just make another question about this issue since its kind of gotten off track?

Comment: Perhaps that's the best idea. It'll get a bit more attention too, but you should probably reduce the amount of code you show and narrow it to the area of concern.

Comment: Alright cool, will do. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your array has nothing to do with this.  It is overwritten on the next launch anyway.  I don't think you are ever deleting your image from the folder, so it is read again on the next launch in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, thanks. I thought that `[self.array removeObject:view];` and `((UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:alertView.tag]).image =nil;` would of done the trick. Do you know what I would need to add in to delete the image from the folder and the array? Sorry for the novice questions again, I'm still learning as I go here.

Comment: Image is not a file reference, it is a pointer to the location in memory where the image is being stored.  You must delete the file explicitly with nsfilemanager.

Comment: Thank you. So, should I add `[fileManager removeItemAtPath:view error:NULL];` under `[self.array removeObject:view];`?

Comment: Not exactly, you need the file path so you need to save that info when you load the pictures.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I think that I already saved that info in viewDidLoad in my code above, and it may be called docFiles, or docsDir. And, my code is based on tags, and I set `view` to figure out which tag has been selected to be deleted. This is getting kind of messy lol

Comment: You arent saving it.  You need to keep a reference to each fullPath you get above.  The two you mentioned are just directories.